# Remove specific segment from a URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I am using codeigniter 2.xx, and this is my view code:

```
<a  href="users/user_info/<?=$row->user_name;?>/<?php echo $row->user_id;?>"></a>
```

And this is my controller code:

```
function user_info($name, $id)
{   
    $info['info']       =   $this->user_model->user_info($id);
    $data['content']    =   $this->load->view('home',$info,true);
    $this->load->view('template',$data);
}
```

When I click on the link I get this url: `http://localhost/users/user_info/name/id`

I want to remove last id segment so my url becomes: `http://localhost/users/user_info/name`. How can I do this? I read about uri segment but it doesn't solve my question.

Comment: Are you trying to read the current URL, or change an output url?

Comment: just don't pass it as a reference, or us the name as an internal id? I'm not sure what you want to achieve here, please clarify your question.

Comment: @sman591 I want to change output url.

Comment: @Jakub id reference is also required so i don't remove it.

Comment: @AzamAlvi "name" is string or its equal to username ?

Comment: its user name like `Azam Alvi`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the current URL and remove the /id from it, simply:

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

$paths = explode('/', trim(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/'));

unset($paths[count($paths)-1]);

$new_url = '/' . implode('/', $paths);

echo $new_url;
```

Which removes the last URL segment,  outputting `/users/user_info/name` if visiting the page `/users/user_info/name/id`

Alternatively, you could change $url to the string in the href="...", but then again couldn't you just remove the code directly from the href?

Comment: this will do well but it will not solve because the link from href is getting name and id so how this will work.and thanks for ur ans

Comment: So you don't want the name to be outputted into the href="" either?

Comment: sorry i can't understand what u r saying. actually i mean to say that how to use this code because i am just using `href` so if change is required then here will be done, my question is that where to use your code.thanks

Comment: Can you not just change `href="users/user_info/<?=$row->user_name;?>/<?php echo $row->user_id;?>"` to `href="users/user_info/<?=$row->user_name;?>"`?

Comment: no i cant because i am using unique id for fetching data and for displaying in url also including name, so i can't change.

Comment: So you want the URL to hide the /id, but want the website to handle the request with a /id?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27684/discussion-between-sman591-and-azam-alvi)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a  href="/users/user_info/<?=$row->user_name;?>"></a>
```

(At href add slash at the start) And at controller..

```
function user_info($name)
{   
    $info['info']       =   $this->user_model->user_info($name);
    $data['content']    =   $this->load->view('home',$info,true);
    $this->load->view('template',$data);
}
```

At your user Model set function user_info to catch user by username, not by user id. And you are ready..

Comment: i can't remove id because username may be more then so i m using id so i can't remove id.

Comment: this is not that user name i am using name not username, username is unique bt name is not

Comment: u r right that's y i am using unique id for fetching data and for displaying purpose also using username.

Comment: Then there is no point to put such not unique Name at url ... Better change your idea to (id or (unique)username)..